# What equipment is required to record game play and commentary and post to YouTube?

Tags: video, youtube

My son would like to record game play on PS3 (Minecraft, Lego) and overlay his own commentary and upload these videos to his channel on YouTube? What hardware, software and/or dedicated equipment is required to achieve this?

Comment: Ah, can't have enough Minecraft videos on the web ;)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you're looking for a low cost option, the key words you need to Google are "HDMI HD GAME Capture" which will result in hardware like this [HD 1080P Video Capture HDMI Recorder with SD Card Slot for XBox 360 One PS3 PS4](http://www.gearbest.com/cables-connectors/pp_211791.html?currency=GBP&gclid=CPSc0Lr1s8oCFUGVGwodstEHvg)

- The HDMI pass-through function guarantees smooth HD gaming
  experience even while recording.
- Record 1080P HD video into USB    disk or SD card directly, no PC required.
- Supports all video sources input: HDMI, component, composite.
- Pass through 1080P HDMI to display on big screen.
- Record your voice with video together through microphone input.

£55 + shipping...bargain - and doesn't hog your PC whilst recording.

That should be all you need but, if further editing is required, google some free video editors to try out or you can perform [basic trim and edits on YouTube...here's how.](http://mashable.com/2012/10/19/youtube-video-editing/#t04c4XD6piqm)

Answer (score 0):

You can record the audio side by side using any microphone or mobile phone and sync it with your videos through editing software like iMovie or final cut pro ...https://youtu.be/ZFhk-aM9sM8 using the auto sync function